# How to create a map with custom annotation and region focus when mapView is scrolled or marker is tapped?

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit, mkannotation, mkannotationview

I want to implement a MapKit with an UIView that has the same effect of TripAdvisor and ClassPass app. Basically, I want to add a scrollable view in the bottom of the view and when the user scroll in the map, the bottom view with the marker's information changes with the new marker's details.

Examples of what I want to achieve:

https://uigarage.net/maps-on-ios-by-tripadvisor/

Second example with ClassPass app: 
https://medium.com/classpass-engineering/creating-a-fluid-scroll-experience-on-ios-faeb29be3bdb

Third example, with the code in React Native:
https://codedaily.io/tutorials/9/Build-a-Map-with-Custom-Animated-Markers-and-Region-Focus-when-Content-is-Scrolled-in-React-Native

I was able to create the Apple map with the markers, and the UIView, as can be seen on the next pictures in the links below:
[Storyboard's Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tJI58.png)

[Simulator's Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KL2m8.png)

However, I want that to change the UIView dynamically, based on the map region, or when tapping the marker. How can I reach that result?

**Here's the current code:**

```
  @IBOutlet weak var reviewView2: DesignableView!
    @IBOutlet weak var authorLabel: UILabel!


    @IBOutlet weak var reviewLabel: UILabel!


    @IBOutlet weak var Star1: UIImageView!

    @IBOutlet weak var Star2: UIImageView!

    @IBOutlet weak var Star3: UIImageView!

    @IBOutlet weak var Star4: UIImageView!

    @IBOutlet weak var Star5: UIImageView!

    @IBOutlet weak var authorImageView: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var reviewView: DesignableView!

    var gpxURL: NSURL? {
        didSet {
            clearWaypoints()
             if let url = gpxURL {
                GPX.parse(url: url as URL) { gpx in      // asynchronous
                        if gpx != nil {
                              self.addWayPoints(waypoints: gpx!.waypoints)
                        }
                }
            }
        }
    }

   let urlstring = "Long_Lat"

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
//        gpxURL = URL(string: urlstring)
        gpxURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: urlstring, withExtension: "gpx") as NSURL?

        reviewView.isHidden = true
        reviewView2.isHidden = true


    }

 @IBAction func reviewViewsTapped(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        print("Button tapped")
    }




     // MARK: - MKMapViewDelegate

    func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {
     var view = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationView(withIdentifier: Constants.AnnotationViewReuseIdentifier)

     if view == nil {
         view = MKPinAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: Constants.AnnotationViewReuseIdentifier)


        }else{
               view?.annotation = annotation
           }

        view?.canShowCallout = false

           guard !annotation.isKind(of: MKUserLocation.self) else {
               //for the custom image on current location
                   view?.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "gift")
                   return view
           }


        view?.image = UIImage(named: "gift")

        let scaleTransform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 0.0, y: 0.0)  // Scale
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2, animations: {
            view?.transform = scaleTransform
            view?.layoutIfNeeded()
        }) { (isCompleted) in

            // Nested block of animation
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, animations: {
                view?.alpha = 1.0
                view?.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1.0, y: 1.0)
                AnimationUtility.viewSlideInFromBottom(toTop: view!)
                view?.layoutIfNeeded()
            })
        }


     return view
 }
```

Any idea on how to do that using Swift 5 and UIKit?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

u can use google maps,
set your custom map markers it has all methods you can read more here
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/intro

Comment: I think the perfect example would be ClassPass, with the difference that I want to change the view that contains the user information while the user change the map region. And ClassPass uses MapKit, not Google Map.